# Isolation Forest large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, random-forest, outliers

I have a database that is made of (3862900,19), each column is a different parameter and includes outliers, is it possible to detect outliers in each column simultaneously, or do I have to repeat it 19 times for each column?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to detect outliers in each column simultaneously

Comment: Would you elaborate more with some scripts and improve your answer with showcases on the routine anomaly [dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/real_world.html#kddcup99-dataset)?